# How can I prove to google that a godaddy based site with instapage in my site?

Tags: google, godaddy

I have registered a domain with godaddy and do not have their hosting services just the free instapage.

I want my domain to be actually hosted at google apps.

I have got to the point in google setup where google has asked me to verify that this my domain by adding some metadata in the header of mypage (there are couple of other options as well).

The problem is that because I am not using godaddy's hosting I can not add any thing to the head as instapage only give me edit access to body and some templates.

Is there a way I can verify that this my domain with having to pay for godaddy's hosting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [not your only option](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60216) for verifying domain ownership. The DNS record method should be available to you, at least.

Comment: Yes it is but that also expects me to have access to go dady's control panel which I do not have. I do have login and password but there is not control\admin panel since I did not buy their hosting services.

Comment: alternatively I can buy hosting for 3 months thats the minimum available time and then verify and move over to Google.

Comment: Sorry, but that first comment doesn't seem to make any sense. This has nothing to do with whether they're hosting you. You registered a domain with GoDaddy, have a login for them, but *don't* have access to their DNS administration tools? That's either not right, or GoDaddy is not actually the registrar.

Comment: Well GoDaddy is the registrar and I do not have access to DNS admin tools as far as I know but you sound confident enough so let me double check it (later today) I have a feel that you are right(which would be a good outcome for me :) ). I will get back to you . Appreciate your reply back.

Comment: Okay just checked I was actually never logging from GoDaddy page but rather from a link that GoDaddy had put on my webpage.Yes I have got access to this :) thank you .